# What is the difference between Clojure clojure.core.reducers/fold and Scala fold?

Tags: scala, clojure

I came across that Clojure has `clojure.core.reducers/fold` function.

Also Scala has built-in `fold` function but could not understand that they are working differently or not?

Comment: Could you please explicitly state, that you are talking about `clojure.core.reducers/fold` so answers don't have to guess?  There is no `fold` in `clojure.core` (there is `reduce`) and this what at least I imply from that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about [clojure.core.reducers/fold](https://clojure.org/reference/reducers#_reduce_and_fold).

Scala's default [`fold`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Seq.html) implementation on sequences is very simple:

```
collection.fold(identityElem)(binOp)
```

simply starts with the `identityElem` and then traverses the collection sequentially, and applies the binary operation `binOp` to the already accumulated result and the current sequence value, e.g.

```
(1 to 3).fold(42000)(_ + _)
```

will result in `42000 + 1 + 2 + 3` = `42006`.

Clojure's `fold` with the full signature

```
(r/fold n combinef reducef coll)
```

from the above mentioned package works in parallel in two stages. First, it splits the input into smaller groups of size `n` (approximately), then reduces each group using `reducef`, and finally combines the results of each group using `combinef`.

The main difference is that `combinef` is expected to be both a zeroary **and** binary at the same time (Clojure has multi-ary functions), and `(combinef)` (without arguments) will be invoked to produce identity elements for each partition (thus, [this documentation](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core.reducers/fold) is correct, and [this documentation](https://clojure.org/reference/reducers#_reduce_and_fold) lies).

That is, in order to simulate Scala's fold from the above example, one would have to write something like this:

```
(require '[clojure.core.reducers :as r])

(r/fold 3 (fn ([] 42000) ([x y] y)) + [1 2 3])
```

And in general, Scala's `fold`

```
collection.fold(identityElement)(binOp)
```

can be emulated by `reducers/fold` as follows:

```
(r/fold collectionSize (fn ([] identityElem) ([x y] y)) binOp collection)
```

(note the `([x y] y)` contraption that throws away the first argument, it's intentional).

I guess the interface wasn't intended to be used with any zero-binary operations that are not monoids, that's the reason why Scala's `fold` is so awkward to simulate using Clojure's `fold`. If you want something that behaves like Scala's `fold`, use `reduce` in Clojure.

---

**EDIT**

Oh, wait. The documentation actually states that

> combinef must be associative, and, when called with no
>   arguments, (combinef) must produce its identity element

that is, we are actually *forced* to use a monoid as the `combinef`, so the above `42000, ([x y] y)`-example is actually invalid, and the behavior is actually undefined. The fact that I somehow got the `42006` out was a *hack* in the strictly technical sense that it relied on undefined behavior of a library function to obtain the desired result `42006`.

Taking this extra information into account, I'm not sure whether Scala's `fold` can be simulated by Clojure's `core.reducers/fold` at all. Clojure's `fold` seems to be constrained to reductions with a monoid, whereas Scala's fold is closer to the general `List` catamorphism, at the expense of parallelism.

Answer (score 2):

The `clojure.core.reducers` namespace is a specialized implementation designed for parallel processing of large datasets.  You can find full docs here:

https://clojure.org/reference/reducers.

```
(r/fold reducef coll)
(r/fold combinef reducef coll)
(r/fold n combinef reducef coll)
```

> r/fold takes a reducible collection and partitions it into groups of
>   approximately n (default 512) elements. Each group is reduced using
>   the reducef function. The reducef function will be called with no
>   arguments to produce an identity value in each partition. The results
>   of those reductions are then reduced with the combinef (defaults to
>   reducef) function. When called with no arguments, (combinef) must
>   produce its identity element - this will be called multiple times.
>   Operations may be performed in parallel. Results will preserve order.

---

Until you are maxing out your machine, you should just stick to the basic `reduce` function:

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce

This is essentially the same as Scala's `fold` function:

```
(reduce + 0 [1 2 3 4 5]) => 15
```

where the function signature is:

```
(reduce <op> <init-val> <collection-to-be-reduced> )
```

Comment: how it differs from Scala's fold?

Comment: This somehow seems to answer a slightly different question that is more pleasant to answer. The actual question didn't ask for comparison of Scala's `fold` with Clojure's `reduce`, it asked about Clojure's `fold`.